# read and get value btw whitespace and another character

Tags: c++

how to get the 1st name. here is the sample of data.. first name here is Owen, Florencio. I need to read and get the value frm whitespace to ; ??

> ```
> Owen;Grzegorek;Howard Miller Co;15410 Minnetonka Industrial Rd;Minnetonka;Hennepin;MN;55345;952-939-2973;952-939-4663;owen@grzegorek.com;http://www.owengrzegorek.com
> Florencio;Hollberg;Hellenic Museum & Cultural Ctr;2211 Kenmere Ave;Burbank;Los
> ```

Comment: 1. Can you improve the question a little bit so I can understand what you're actually asking?  and 2. Can you show us what you've tried so far and what problems you've run into attempting that?

Answer (score 0):

Use string::find to find the first instance of semi-colon, and do a string::substr.

```
string str = "Florencio;Hollberg;Hellenic Museum & Cultural Ctr;2211 Kenmere Ave;Burbank;Los";
std::size_t pos = str.find(";");
str = str.substr(0, pos);
cout << str << endl;
```

Output:

```
Florencio
```

Of course, you have to modify the code to suit your needs.